error when starting the project Android Studio
I have never worked with Android Studio. I downloaded the application and copied the project from Github. When starting the project, it gives the error: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 has terminated. After reading the forum, I went to the log file and saw the following:
Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 has terminated.
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:92)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:272)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:29)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:24)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)`

I don’t know what this means and what to do about it.
